# How to bind DataTemplate controls to ObservableCollections' item property

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I'm trying to create a custom listbox to display some data, however I can't find the right way to set binding between DataTemplate controls and the items properties.

I have the following POCO class:

```vb
Namespace Model
    Public Class Version

        Property Numero As String

        Property Checksum As String

    End Class
End Namespace
```

And this ViewModel class:

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Namespace ViewModel
    Public Class VersionViewModel
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged


        Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged


        Private _ListaVersiones As ObservableCollection(Of Model.Version)
        Public Property ListaVersiones As ObservableCollection(Of Model.Version)
            Get
                Return _ListaVersiones
            End Get
            Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of Model.Version))
                _ListaVersiones = value
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Versiones")
            End Set
        End Property

        Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
        End Sub


    End Class
End Namespace
```

I'm trying to use this ViewModel in the following XAML:

```xml
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Projeto.ViewModel"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:VersionViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
        <Style 
            BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBox}}"
            TargetType="ListBox"
            x:Key="EstiloGridVersion">

            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Background="Blue">
                            <Border Background="Red" x:Name="border" BorderBrush="Gray" CornerRadius="6" Height="30" BorderThickness="1">

                                <!-- The error is in the Binding Path -->
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Path=ListaVersiones.Numero}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ListBox x:Name="GridVersion" Style="{StaticResource EstiloGridVersion}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=ListaVersiones}">

    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

The TextBlock binding option is giving me an error "cannot resolve symbol X".

What is the right way to do this?

### UPDATE

Here is the Window Loaded event code:

```vb
Class MainWindow

    Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim versiones As New VersionViewModel
        versiones.ListaVersiones = New ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of Model.Version)()
        versiones.ListaVersiones.Add(New Model.Version() With {.Numero = "07.0201", .Checksum = "0450a4s6540a6s5006a5s4"})
        versiones.ListaVersiones.Add(New Model.Version() With {.Numero = "07.0207", .Checksum = "243jkh234jh23j3406a5s4"})

        GridVersion.ItemsSource = versiones
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: `ItemsSource` is `ListaVersiones` so each item is of `Version` type so `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Numero}"/>` should work

Comment: It gives the same error while in design time: Cannot resolve symbol Numero. And when the application is executed it is just closed, without crash messages (using both ListaVersiones.Numero and Numero).

Comment: It may give the error in design time (sometimes designer have problem resolving correct context) but it should work in run time. If your application closes I think is for different reason then problem with this binding

Comment: also when you raise `NotifyPropertyChanged` for `ListaVersiones` property you need to pass _ListaVersiones_ and not _Versiones_ as you do at the moment

Comment: I've added the rest of the code for the entire app. I can't find I reason to close automatically without showing any error. Fixed the NotifyPropertyChanged but the app still closes.

Comment: Does it even compile? How are you able to do this `GridVersion.ItemsSource = versiones`? `VersionViewModel` does not implement `IEnumerable` from what I can see. You should assign `versiones.ListaVersiones` instead

Comment: It was compiling, but that was the problem. After changing to GridVersion.ItemsSource = versiones.ListaVersiones it is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ItemsSource` is set to `ObservableCollection<Model.Version>` each item will be of `Model.Version` type and this will be `DataContext` for each `ListBoxItem` so in your `DataTemplate` you need to refer to a property of `Model.Version`

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Numero}"/>
```

also, it should not compile, but problem is when you assign `ItemsSource`

```
GridVersion.ItemsSource = versiones
```

you should assign `versiones.ListaVersiones` instead

```
GridVersion.ItemsSource = versiones.ListaVersiones
```

another thing is that when you raise `NotifyPropertyChanged` for `ListaVersiones` property you need to pass *ListaVersiones* (exact property name) and not *Versiones* as you do at the moment

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("ListaVersiones")
```

and since you set `ItemsSource` manually you don't need to do it in XAML

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=ListaVersiones}"
```

the new `VersionViewModel` instance you create in `Window_Loaded` **is not the same instance** that you create in XAML

```
<vm:VersionViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
```

Comment: How can I use <vm:VersionViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/> instance in my VB code?

Comment: If you want to manually initialize some properties that I would not use it that way. Create one instance of `VersionViewModel` in MainWindow and keep in local variable, say `_myVersionViewModel`. Set it as `DataContext` (`Me.DataContext = _myVersionViewModel`) and change `ItemsSource` binding to `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListaVersiones}"` and then you can do `_myVersionViewModel.ListaVersiones = ...` and UI should update  without manually updating `ItemsSource` (`GridVersion.ItemsSource = ....`)

Comment: Why are you saying that you would not use it this way (by setting DataContext)? Is there any drawback when using it like this?

Comment: Creating view model in XAML is good if you want to create instance of view model and let it roll from that point (without manual initialization). But since you want to initialize `ListaVersiones` manually, and want to work on instance created in XAML, then you need to first find that resource and work on that which makes in unnecessary more difficult and less clear in my opinion

Comment: In the case of no manual initialization, I should have a command in my ViewModel to load the data into my ObservableCollection in some event from XAML. Right?